# Если файл не создан не работает

Tags: python, json

Косяк в том, что если в функции write открывать файл с 'w' то он стирается и json выдает ошибку, что не может декодировать пустой файл. Если файла нету не работает вообще и выдает ошибку что не находит его.

```
import os
import argparse
import tempfile
import json

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--key", type=str)
parser.add_argument("--val", type=str)
parser.parse_args()
args = parser.parse_args()
storage_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'storage.data')


def write(key, value):
    with open(storage_path, 'r+') as f:
        data = read()
        if key in data:
            data[key].append(value)
        else:
            data[key] = []
            data[key].append(value)
        f.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, f)


def read():
    with open(storage_path, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data


if args.key and args.val:
    write(args.key, args.val)
elif args.key:
    print(", ".join([item for item in read()[args.key]]))
```

Comment: не используйте сломанный код в качестве спецификации задачи. Не нужно весь код который у вас есть приводить. Создайте минимальный пример кода, который демонстрирует проблему (уберите всё лишнее, не относящееся к проблеме). Опишите словами желаемое поведение (на входе то-то, на выходе это). После этого подробно по шагам опишите что фактически происходит. Явно укажите отличия от желаемого поведения [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

модуль `json` в `python` не имеет возможность дописывать в файл. Поэтому вы должны сначала считать всю информацию из файла, изменить её, и записать новую в файл.